# C# Classic Windows Desktop App avoid UAC

Tags: c#, windows-10, uac

I have installed a custom app, classic desktop, win32, that runs as a custom shell on Windows 10 Pro on over a 6 thousand machines, users located in many cities.

That app does not access even program files, nor devices, just a WPF app written in C#, with dependency to some .DLL's. Indeed the app is installed in a custom folder, `C:\CustomApp\`

The app manifest specifies the user level of security and runs ok:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

On a day to day base the app runs ok, just as stated with local user privileges which are not administrative, just standard user.

Having an autoupdater feature, when a new version is found, the app asks for administrator privilege, which is a huge problem due to the amount of devices and geographic dispersion. On the other hand we don't use Active Directories, so no way of Group Policy.

I need the updating process to behave as any Android app, say it just asks for a click to accept update, does not ask for elevated password.

Is it possible? I'm sure it is possible, have read a lot of questions related,  the majority of which states that execution privileges are granted on the manifest, which already is done. My problem is to avoid elevated privileges at installation, say the new version installation, on execution there is no problem at all.

Thanks,

Comment: I think one of the issues could be if the application is installed in the Program files directory. If that is the case, a auto update will need write privileges to update. The directory is protected. Try put it in another dir, and see what happens.

Comment: Users should only have read/execute and list contents on the C: drive.  the app was most likely installed with Admin rights.  If the folder inherits permission you will get the prompt for admin credentials.

Comment: @Sorceri that's an interesting pont,  actually is installed at c:\customApp,  so based on your comment,  it's better to install inside a non privileged folder?  say,  Program File (86).

Comment: @datelligence  Appdata\Roaming folder is you best bet as they should have write permissions there.   The program file (86) Will have the same  read/execute and list contents as the C: drive

Comment: This depends on the rights of the users which may be established at a group level.  I'm assuming this is networked on a job site where the users are controlled from a remote server.  You can modify the privileges there and or allow for this app to work per user. IT work to be short.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII as I stated in the question we dont have GP, acttive directories or any MS managment product.

Comment: @Sorceri I'm sure your solution can be a valid answer,  I installed on the folder suggested by you,  UAC doesn't prompt which is awesome,  however can't delete and write files,  Code 5 errror message,  any ideas in which location it can be done without the delete/write restriction,  thanks.

Comment: @datelligence Apologies, I didn't see that.

Comment: @datelligence  If it is installed with elevated privileges you can set the permissions during the install.  also appdata\local (%localappdata%) and if all else fails since it appears to just be a location to store %userprofile%